# Norm along row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas Dataframe with N columns representing the coordinates of a vector (for example X, Y, Z, but could be more than 3D).

I would like to aggregate the dataframe along the rows with an arbitrary function that combines the columns, for example the norm: `(X^2 + Y^2 + Y^2)`.

I want to do something similar to what is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951341/pandas-dataframe-aggregate-function-using-multiple-columns) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10009468/groupby-functions-in-python-pandas-like-sumcol-1col-2-weighted-average-etc) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951341/pandas-dataframe-aggregate-function-using-multiple-columns) but I want to keep it general enough that the number of columns can change and it behaves like

```
DataFrame.mean(axis = 1)
```

or

```
DataFrame.sum(axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I found a faster solution than what @elyase suggested:

```
np.sqrt(np.square(df).sum(axis=1))
```

Comment: there is also np.linalg.norm, but for some reason the "manual version" you supplied above is faster

Comment: at least in my case, this could be speeded up by doing df.values

Comment: @Wizard The reason why the "manual version" is faster than `np.linalg.norm()` I've discussed in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64948677/). Note that if views are involved or `df` has a lot of columns, `np.linalg.norm()` eventually wins.

Answer (score 15):

Numpy provides norm... Use:

```
np.linalg.norm(df[['X','Y','Z']].values,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 10):

One line, using whatever function you desire (including lambda functions), e.g.

`df.apply(np.linalg.norm, axis=1)`

or

`df.apply(lambda x: (x**2).sum()**.5, axis=1)`

Answer (score 3):

filter the columns by name

```
cols = ['X','Y','Z']
df[cols].mean(axis=1)
df[cols].sum(axis=1)
df[cols].apply(lambda values: sum([v**2 for v in values]), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). Your example would look like this:

```
>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]], columns=['X', 'Y', 'Z'])
     X   Y   Z
0    1   1   0
1    1   0   0

>>> df.apply(lambda x: np.sqrt(x.dot(x)), axis=1)
0    1.414214
1    1.000000
dtype: float64
```

This works for any number of dimensions.

Comment: Thanks! I just stumbled upon a faster solution: `np.sqrt(np.square(df).sum(axis=1))`

Comment: Always prefer column-wise functions to `apply` - for common operations, the former are orders of magnitude faster than a hand-written apply.